# asp.net random image source

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, image

I want to load up a random image while a page it is loading but not sure what the syntax is for either asp:image or just img.

The files are all named the same but with a number at the end so I could do:

```
string Get_RandomImage()
{
   Random random = new Random();
   return "~/images/image" + random.Next(1, 23) + ".jpg";
}
```

But the image is within `<ProgressTemplate>` so I cant just go image.ImageURL = something in the code behind.

How can I call the random method where I am declaring the asp:Image on the aspx page?

```
ImageURL='<%#Get_RandomImage()%>'
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at all you need to initialize `random` variable outside of the `Get_RandomImage` method, make it static and change that method accessibility level to `protected`. Also you can use such expression `ImageURL='<%#Get_RandomImage()%>` only if you call `DataBind` on page or image's parent control.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" >
     <ProgressTemplate>
          <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
               <ContentTemplate>
                    <%--Put your image here--%>
                    <%= DateTime.Now %>
               </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Ok I have it done with Image img = updateProgress.FindControl("randomImg") as Image; img.ImageURL = Get_RandomImage() but while the image is random when the page is refreshed, on postback it does not, even though I can see the source having a random image on every post back. How to fix that?

Comment: You mean async postback with `UpdatePanel` control? If so, do you refreshing updateprogress content on async postback?

Comment: Not sure how that's done. I've "inherited" the code so where would that be set?

Comment: Try to put all content of the `updateProgress` into `UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode="Always"`

Comment: thats an error, it says you cannot have UpdateProgress within UpdatePanel.